# DJI photo has EXIF data with GPS location but QGIS Raster>Convert>Translate shows it in the middle of the sea

Tags: qgis, gdal-translate

I have taken a couple of test photos with a DJI Spark and they contain EXIF GPS data:

- File Name: photo.jpg
- ... {snip}
- File Size: 7.6 MB
- ... {snip}
- Image Description: DCIM/100MEDIA/DJI_0014.JPG
- Camera Model Name: FC1102
- Orientation: Horizontal (normal)
- X Resolution: 72
- Y Resolution: 72
- ... {snip}
- GPS Version ID: 3.2.0.0
- GPS Latitude Ref: North
- GPS Longitude Ref: West
- GPS Altitude Ref: Above Sea Level
- ... {snip}
- About: DJI
- Meta Data Format: image/jpg
- ... {snip}
- GPS Altitude: 29.5 m Above Sea Level
- GPS Latitude: 52 deg 43' 53.00" N
- GPS Longitude: 0 deg 26' 42.00" W
- ... {snip}

That is in the UK but when I use Raster>Convert>Translate:

gdal_translate -of GTiff "C:/Users/User/Documents/DRONE/Test1/photo.JPG" C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_TfJqoT/4f67ec99f4684684946b542883a2d640/OUTPUT.tif

It seems to place it somewhere off the West African coast when I add it to a OSM standard map.

Comment: Please post your test photos.

Answer (score 3):

Your DJI images are geotagged images only.  As you have stated the EXIF data is storing the location of your GNSS camera at the time of image capture.  Warping these images is purging the location data and they are displaying a (0,0) at Null Island.

Consider the [QGIS Vertical Photo Placer](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/vertical_photo_placer/) tool to (roughly) georeference your images directly below the camera location based on azimuth and elevation. This tool does not work well with oblique images unfortunately.  While the Vertical Photo Placer tool does consider elevation your GNSS images will reference the WGS84 vertical datum which is likely to be different than heights above OSGB36.  Therefore, your image footprints will likely be too small or too large.

There are several posts on GIS Stack Exchange regarding the automated process of georeferencing drone images based on EXIF data for your browsing pleasure. There is also [this post on LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/gerry-gabrisch-gisp-2aa3263b_algorithm-based-automated-georeferencing-activity-6910658166561153024-M1gy?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop) (disclaimer, I am the author).